# How can Mybatis generates duplicate Id？Or I should not blame it？

Tags: duplicates, db2, mybatis

I got duplicate ID by the following CREATE STATEMENT and Mapper file. The Datebase I using is DB2. Could anyone help? Thanks a lot!

### [CREATE TABLE]

CREATE TABLE SUP_BCP_TRANS_FLOW (**ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY**, SERIAL_NO VARCHAR(40), BAT_NO VARCHAR(32), PAYER_ACC_NO VARCHAR(40), PAYER_ACC_NAME VARCHAR(255), PAYEE_ACC_NO VARCHAR(40), PAYEE_ACC_NAME VARCHAR(255), PAYEE_PARTY_ID VARCHAR(20), TRAN_AMT DECIMAL(16,2), FEE_AMOUNT DECIMAL(16,2), POSTSCRIPT VARCHAR(300), MEMO VARCHAR(255), RET_TYPE VARCHAR(1), RET_CODE VARCHAR(8), RET_MSG VARCHAR(255), OLD_RET_CODE VARCHAR(32), OLD_RET_MSG VARCHAR(255), STR1 VARCHAR(1024), STR2 VARCHAR(1024), STR3 VARCHAR(1024), STR4 VARCHAR(1024), STR5 VARCHAR(1024), SER_NO VARCHAR(20), OTH_SERIAL_NO VARCHAR(40), NOTICE_STATUS VARCHAR(1), CREATE_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP, UPDATE_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP, NOTICE_TIME INTEGER);

### [Mapper File]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmaTa.png

insert into SUP_BCP_TRANS_FLOW   (BAT_NO,SERIAL_NO,PAYER_ACC_NO,PAYEE_ACC_NO,PAYEE_ACC_NAME,PAYEE_PARTY_ID,TRAN_AMT,FEE_AMOUNT,POSTSCRIPT,   MEMO,RET_TYPE,RET_CODE,RET_MSG,OLD_RET_CODE,OLD_RET_MSG,STR1,STR2,STR3,STR4,STR5,SER_NO,OTH_SERIAL_NO,NOTICE_STATUS,NOTICE_TIME) values
    
      (
      #{item.batNo,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.serialNo,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.payerAccNo,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.payeeAccNo,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.payeeAccName,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.payeePartyId,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.tranAmt,jdbcType=DECIMAL},
      #{item.feeAmount,jdbcType=DECIMAL},
      #{item.postscript,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.memo,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.retType,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.retCode,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.retMsg,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.oldRetCode,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.oldRetMsg,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.str1,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.str2,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.str3,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.str4,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.str5,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.serNo,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.othSerialNo,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.noticeStatus,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{item.noticeTime,jdbcType=INTEGER}
      )

Comment: please edit your question to add missing information, the full text of the exception showing which constraint is involved. Things might not be what you assume.

Comment: Thank you for reply, mao. No exception occurs in my application. All my question is about the column ID. As the CREATE TABLE statement shows above, the ID column is defined by "ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY", so I don't need to set the value in the Service layer of my application. I assumed it would be generated by Mybatis, or DB2. And in fact, when I query from database, I find the ID column has its value in every object. But...but...what makes me puzzled is the ID column duplicate its value in different object occasionally！Please help me, mao. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Mybatis - instead, it is caused by the table design.

What you observe is the expected behaviour for the `GENERATED BY DEFAULT...` clause.

But you seem to expect the behaviour should correspond with `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY...` clause along with a `PRIMARY KEY(id)` clause.  The combination of these two clauses will guarantee uniqueness.

But specifying only the `GENERATED BY DEFAULT...` clause, with no unique index or primary key constraint will **not** guarantee uniqueness for that column.

The `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` means that Db2 will generate a unique value **only** when the appplications do not provide a value. But if any application chooses to supply a value then Db2 will use that value instead (and will not generate a new value), and that application-supplied value does not need to be unique **unless** your DDL also specified the `PRIMARY KEY(id)`  clause.  Remember that more than one application (or person) may be able to insert rows into the table.

If you want to ensure the column named 'id' has rows with a unique value in the 'id' column then you must arrange for the table to have a unique index. The easiest way to do that at the time of table-creation is to specify `PRIMARY KEY(id)` in the `CREATE TABLE...` statement. You can also create the unique index afterwards, separately, with the `create unique index` statement, or with an `alter table ... add constraint...` clause to specify the primary key, although you must first remove any duplicate values by adjustments beforehand.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mao. Where are you based? We can have a cup of coffee, haha... I will    follow your suggestion. But I want to ask another question. Perhaps, I should ask it together with the one above. The fact I missing is that I find two objects just the same--Yes, every attribute(column) is the same，including ID.  Could you tell me how this happens? Thank you, mao.

Comment: @JiajieDu If you have rows with all columns duplicated, it is caused by errors in the application.